# Взаимодействие HttpClient с textView

Tags: android, многопоточность, httpclient

У меня есть поток с httpclient, я хочу что бы по нажатию или по получению ответа и распрасивания ответа изменял textview на распарсеный ответ.

```
package com.example.hondle.biling.fragments;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.hondle.biling.R;

import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;

public class FragPay extends Fragment {

    public final String TAG = "FragPay";

    private TextView textview;

    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;
    public String text = "";

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
    public FragPay() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static FragPay newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        FragPay fragment = new FragPay();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pay, container, false);

        textview = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.info);

        Button Btn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);
        Btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "BtnClick");
                Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
                thread.start();

            }
        });

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return view;

    }






    Handler handler = new Handler();
    public Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        public void run() {
            String token = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("access_token");
            Log.d(TAG, token);
            DefaultHttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
            ResponseHandler GetResponse = new BasicResponseHandler();
            HttpGet http = new HttpGet("mysite.info/api/v1.3.0/pay/history?access_token="+token);
            //получаем ответ от сервера
            try {

                String response = (String) hc.execute(http, GetResponse);
                Log.d(TAG, response);

                JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(response);

                String error = jobj.getString("error");
                Log.d(TAG, error);
                JSONObject Jerror = new JSONObject(error);

                String code = Jerror.getString("code");
                Log.d(TAG, code);
                text = Jerror.getString("text");
                Log.d(TAG, text);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    };


    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }


    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

UPD: Проблема в том, что я понятия не имею как это сделать. Нельзя создать TextView в потоке или задать сеттер. И поэтому я в тупике и прошу помощи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте `AsyncTask`, где в `onPostExecute` будете устанавливать свой результат в `TextView`

Можете конечно использовать `Handler`, передав в него результат и установив его в `TextView`. Или `runOnUiThread`, но все же лучше `AsyncTask`.

Comment: А как в асинктаске получить intent? он же не привязан, не к одному активити.

Comment: @SlavaNenashev Как я понял, Вы об этом: `getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("access_token");`. Просто при запуске передавайте уже готовый токен в качестве параметра. Или сделайте его полем внешнего класса.

Comment: Создавать новый токен, это уже кастыль,да и все равно прийдется передавать пароль и логин. Если его создавать как поле внешнего класса (public static String tokens = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("access_token");
) , со статиком ругается getActivity, а без статика в asyncTask ругается что он не статичен.

Comment: @SlavaNenashev, `AsyncTask` не должен быть `static`, тогда и ругаться не будет. Ну если передать как параметр это костыль, тогда даже не знаю что предложить.

Comment: AsyncTask и не статичен, я про то что он требует что бы public String tokens = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("access_token"); Что бы он был статичен, если он вне класса AsyncTask